# Prove that $\arctan{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}$ has only one solution on the set of real numbers.

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that $\arctan{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}$ has only one solution on the set of real numbers.

I need some help with it, would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Answer (score 4):

For $x > 0$, $\arctan x$ is strictly increasing while $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is strictly decreasing.

For $x < 0$, $\arctan x < 0 < \dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

What does this tell you about the number of positive and negative solutions?

Comment: So it follows that the only solution must be when x>0, somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Infer from the graph plotting. 
Draw the graph of $y=1/x^2$ on paper and then make the graph of $\arctan(x)$ wherever they intersect is your solution and number of points of intersection are your number of solution. This is answer is given on the assumption that you know the basic graphs of $1/x^2$ and $\arctan(x)$.